# regex for matching words starting with special chars

Tags: regex, special-characters, word-boundaries

Im trying to match #TEST in a string.. lets say its "this is a #TEST"

The script that does the matching automatically wraps the search string in \b tags so the resulting regex would look like this: \b#TEST\b .. this obviously doesn't work.

How can i change the search string to make it work ?

EDIT: i opted to change the wrapping function so the generated expression looks like this:

```
(?<!\S)#TEST(?!\S)
```

edit2: escaping my text..

Comment: `\b#TEST\b` would only match `(?<=\w|^)# ... ` in this case. Explain again why you can't change the script that automatically puts `\b` there ?

Comment: The list of strings to be matched is by far normal words and is mostly maintained by non-tech people with no knowledge of regular expressions. This case is an edge case so its just to keep the list simple (mostly) for the people maintaining it. I could change the script to not wrap the string but then the list would be gibberish to some.. it actually gave me an idea.. using (?<!\S)#TEST(?!\S) gives me what i want and will also work with the rest of the list.. so i guess im changing the wrapper :)

Comment: `(?<!\S) .. (?!\S)` as a wrapper is better than `(?<=\s) .. (?=\s)` because it uses another negative condition that satisfies BOS/EOS. However it might miss stuff like words wrapped in punctuation, like what `\b` would give you. Another alternative is to use a conditional boundary as a wrapper. `(?(?=\w)\b) .. (?(?<=\w)\b)` This would examine the first and last letters for word characters, then apply a `\b` assertion if found. Could even mix it.  `(?(?=\w)\b|(?<!\S)) .. (?(?<=\w)\b|(?!\S))`

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use:

```
(^|\W)TEST\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL2fP4/1)

i.e. match line start or a non-word character before `TEST` on left hand side.

Comment: What do you get when you put in the auto-word boundaries `\b(^|\W)TEST\b` ?

Comment: Did I mention anywhere to put `\b` before this? If user can submit `#TEST` input then better not to use `\b` before it.

Comment: You lost me. `\W` matches `#`. Maybe you didn't read the OP statement about the script that auto-wraps `\b`'s. So changing your regex to `\b(^|\W)TEST\b` won't ever match ' #Test'

Comment: If OP is willing to drop `\b` then why are sticking with old requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The '\' character is escaping the 'b' character. Replace '\b' with '\\b', assuming your function is literally wrapping the search string with '\b'.

So:
    '\\b#TEST\\b'

Answer (score 0):

You could sort of overcome that by asserting a #, but it won't be part of the match.
However, it won't match anything else either.

`\b(?<=#)TEST\b`

So pass in `(?<=#)TEST`